# Gurobi Installation Problems MacOSX

Tags: installation, osx-elcapitan, gurobi

I have a macbook air running El Capitan 10.11.12

I'm getting a specific error when I try and install Gurobi on my computer. I've already installed it on two iMacs and had no problems... 
I download the package for the most recent version 8.1.0, and then click through the installer. After it finishes, I type the 'grbgetkey #blah' command in the terminal to connect it with my academic license, and I get the error 'command no found'. I suspect there may be some problem with my $PATH variable?

Comment: Maybe research over on Ask Different? https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you already try the absolute path `/Library/gurobi810/mac64/bin/grbgetkey` in the terminal?